# Can I amend a commit to the master branch from a new local branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-amend

I recently committed a file to the master branch of my work's repository.

I then created a new local branch to work on other things, but realised I had missed something on the original commit. I made the changes while in the new branch. Would git commit --amend work, or will I need to make a fresh commit? Am I right in assuming that git commit --amend with just amend the the file on the git from my new file in my new local branch

Comment: Just FYI, git commit --amend WILL create a fresh commit... though based on your old one. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Branch is 'the problem' here

Amending is still committing - it still happens on same branch, so:

- committing on master
- switching branches to "new local branch"
- making changes there

Means that if you do git commit, it adds a new node on "new local branch", not even touching the master.

### Option 1: git commit --amend on master branch

```
$ git checkout master
// apply changes here
$ git commit --amend
```

This creates new commit REPLACING current tip of master branch (most likely previous commit you did there, unless you or others worked there already, previous commit was pushed, etc.).

### Option 2: git commit on master branch

```
$ git checkout master
// apply changes here
$ git commit -m "New commit, new commit message"
```

Less elegant. But if you pushed? VERY attractive.

### Option 3: git commit on "new local branch" and cherry pick and squash

```
// changes applied on local branch creating commit with SOME_SHA
$ git checkout master
$ git cherry-pick "new local branch name here"
```

This applies changes introduced by the commit at the tip of the "new local branch". You may have conflicts, if branches are too different.

```
$ git rebase -i
```

And here you need to squash the commits into one. ONLY DO SO IF YOU HAVEN'T PUSHED THE CHANGES!

Somewhat over the top option if you ask me. :-)

### "Oh no! I pushed!" options

Either Option 2, or... `git revert SHA-of-original-commit` followed by making ALL the changes and committing.

I'd only use it if something in that original commit was actually bad/harmful.